# bind a polymer template to html5 video.textTracks

Tags: html, video, data-binding, polymer

I try to create a html5 video timeline where all the tracks and the cues are displayed using polymer.

this is the code I have so far, but the binding does not work. It always displays a length of 0:

```
<polymer-element name="video-timeline">
    <template>
        <video id="testVideo" src="./path/to/video.webm" width="300" controls="controls"></video>
        <button on-click="{{addTrack}}">Add Track</button>
        <template bind="{{$.testVideo.textTracks}}">
            <p>Item count: {{length}}</p>
            <ul>
                <template repeat>
                    <li>{{kind}}</li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('video-timeline', {
            addTrack: function() {
                var track = this.$.testVideo.addTextTrack('metadata', 'label');
                track.mode = 'showing';
            },
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

a binding would be useful because editing cues and tracks will folow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like the following:

```html
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="video-timeline" attributes="src">
  <template>
    <div>
      <video id="testVideo" src="{{src}}" width="300" controls></video>
    </div>
    <button on-tap="{{addTrack}}">Add Track</button>
    <p>Item count: {{textTracks.length}}</p>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{textTrack in textTracks}}">
        <li>{{textTrack.kind}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      textTracks: null,
      
      addTrack: function() {
        var track = this.$.testVideo.addTextTrack('metadata', 'label');
        track.mode = 'showing';
        this.textTracks.push(track);
      },
      
      ready: function() {
       this.textTracks = [];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<video-timeline src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg"></video-timeline>
```

One of the problems with your approach is that Polymer's [mutation observers](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/mutation-observers.html) can't detect when `textTracks` are added to `$.testVideo`. The syntax you were using for your `repeat`ed template was also incorrect.

The approach I went with uses an array defined on the Polymer element (`this.textTracks`) as a sort of proxy, and updates the contents of the array each time you add a new track.

This should work for your stated use case, with the caveat that if your `<video>`'s tracks get updated outside of the `addTrack()` handler, the array won't be updated and the rendered `<template repeat="{{}}">` will be inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you for this well explained example.This approach was also the first I cam up with.   
 
I thought it might be possible to improve it in these point:   
1. reuse the already existing track and cue arrays from the video element, without the need to maintain a copy  
2. A more independent and optionally timeline, where the video element is not included in the video-timeline element.     

I think I need to do it with event listeners without the polymer sugaring ;-)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) fired by `<video>`, but I didn't see anything specific as being fired when the tracks are modified. If there is an event, you can probably listen for it via Polymer's native event handling.