# Attach event handler to Polymer core element

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm doing my first steps with `Polymer`. The documentation is quite nice about which elements are available, but I'm missing some infos about event handling. I have the following example:

```
<core-header-panel flex>                                  
  <core-toolbar>
    <core-icon-button icon='menu' on-click='my_handler'></core-icon-button>
  </core-toolbar>
</core-header-panel>
```

My test handler is defined like this:

```
var my_handler = function() {
  alert('!!!');
};
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-icon-button), I don't see any specification of available events. Where do I find them? I tried `on-click` and `on-tap` without success. I consider this as some kind of "Hello World!" example, so I must be missing something. Can somebody explain how to tell the button to call my handler if it's clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Polymer >= 1.0 curly braces aren't necessary for event handlers anymore.

**Old answer**

In Polymer you need the moustache in each binding

```
 on-click='{{my_handler}}'
```

You can find a complete example in this question [bind a polymer template to html5 video.textTracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935007)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that [declarative on-* event handlers](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) only work if you're inside a <polymer-element> or inside an [auto-binding template](http://blog.polymer-project.org/howto/2014/09/11/template-is-autobinding/).